# How to pass a string array as a JSON argument

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass a couple of arguments to my JSON callback, however the string[] argument remains null. How do I need to pass the string array from javascript to get this working?

Javscript function:

```
function jsonCallback(jsonCallbackID, argumentsArray) {
var argumentValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < argumentsArray.length; i++) {
    argumentValues.push('' + $("#" + argumentsArray[i]).val());
}

// build request
var url = encodeURI("/DataEntry/JsonCallback/");
var data = ({ jsonCallbackID: jsonCallbackID, jsonCallbackValues: argumentValues, rndvalue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000001) });

// fire request
$.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {});
```

The actual callback C# function:

```
        public JsonResult JsonCallback(int jsonCallbackID, string[] jsonCallbackValues)
    { }
```

This function does get called however, argument 'jsonCallbackValues' is null.

**EDIT**

To get this working I did the following:

```
var data = ({ jsonCallbackID: jsonCallbackID, jsonCallbackValues: argumentValues.toString(), rndvalue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000001) });
```

And split the jsonCallbackValues string at "," to get the resulting array.

Comment: What's the value of "argumentValues" before it gets sent to the service?

Comment: The value of argumentValues is:rgumentValues: Array[3]
0: "1111aa"
1: "BE"
2: "24041"
length: 3

Comment: is the jsonCallbackID sending through all fine? The serialization of the jsonCallbackvalues should be all fine from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, jsconCallbackID is sent through fine.. jsonCallbackValues is null however

Comment: By using getJSON you are basically executing an ajax call with content type of json. That will trigger the model-binder on the server side to assume all the values you are sending up are in JSON serializable format. If they are not than the JSON model-binder on the server-side is unable to populate your parameters correctly, hence `null`. If you are telling it you are passing JSON than you need to pass JSON serializable parameters.

Comment: Francois: very useful info, I did not know that. Is there an AJAX call I can make, that will handle object parameters correctly and automatically?

Comment: @Arthur: `getJSON` is the same as `$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});` If you want more control you can use `.ajax()` directly. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ There you can specify the exact content type and so on. In your scenario though if `getJSON` and `$.toJSON` works, then happy days :)

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to JSON API ...

```
var data = {
   jsonCallbackID:jsonCallbackID,
   jsonCallbackValues: JSON.stringify(argumentValues),
   rndvalue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000001)
};
// your 
$.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {});
```

Comment: I did this indeed, the result is a comma seperated list in the jsonCallbackValues argument, guessing from Spekdrum's answer below, this is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a serialized language, so you can't put objects inside.

You should build your array in JSON format:

jsonCallbackValues : ["value1", "value2"...]

Comment: Thanks! I did try something similar as a workaround, but it seems from your question that this is the only option I have.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
var data = ({ jsonCallbackID: jsonCallbackID, jsonCallbackValues: $.toJSON(argumentValues), rndvalue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000001) });
```

I have used a JSON jQuery plugin from http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

In the controller method change it to 
    string jsonCallbackValuesArray

Then use
    JavaScriptSerializer orJSON.Net 
to convert the JSON string into String []

Comment: Yeah, this is similar to the answer above, I'm serializing / de-serializing in a similar fashion now. But thank you!